# How to convert all datatable records in JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I want to convert datatable records in JSON. However, I'm done with the code but that code is converting only 10 records (1st page of datatable). I've total of 20 records (2 pages). How to achieve this in jquery?

Following is the code which is converting only 10 records (1st page):

```
function tableToJSON(tblObj){  
   var data = [];
   var $headers = $(tblObj).find("th");
   var $rows = $(tblObj).find("tbody tr").each(function(index) {
   $cells = $(this).find("td");
   data[index] = {};
   $cells.each(function(cellIndex) {
     data[index][$($headers[cellIndex]).html()] = $(this).html();
   });    
});
  return data;
}

var myData = tableToJSON($("#list"));
console.log('2>>> ' + JSON.stringify(myData));
```

**Note:** Datatable and pagination is working fine as desired. I just want to convert all the records of the datatable into JSON.

Comment: which library you are using for the (to generate) table?

Comment: Pagination of DataTables is done server side. So if the table only shows 10 records it will only request 10 records. There is no way to get the missing records from javascript. I would suggest to do a server request for the whole data and process this

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff table shows all records that I'm getting from db, however, my question is when I'm going to convert those records into JSON object, it converts only 10 records which is on 1st page. How to convert all?

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff and pagination is working fine

Comment: No, table is not showing all records. It only shows the records on the selected page and so it only loads the records for the selected page. If you select the next/prev page there will be a new request for data on the server.

Comment: @Alfred I'm using datatables latest version i.e 1.11.2v with bootstrap 4.

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff my dear bro, I'm happy with the datatable and its pagination. It's working fine as desired. I request you to read my question again.

Comment: Once you start using [tag:datatables] you have to keep using it - don't try and manipulate the HTML/DOM.  Get your data from datatables via the API.  See https://datatables.net/reference/api/data()

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff you're correct *if* the data is server-side.  Pagination of datatables is only done server-side if the data is server-side.  In this case, there's no evidence that it's server-side data and datatables will paginate client-based data quite happily without making any server request.

Comment: @freedomn-m If the data would be client side, the OP should use the data and not grab something from a table. But in the end it makes no difference. Th OP is not willing to accept that his approach is totally wrong

Comment: @ClausBönnhoff absolutely

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code to disable pagination and see if the issue exists;

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    paging: false
} );
```

This will populate all rows in db. In this case, `.find("tbody tr")` in your code will be able to find all data in table, and if paging is enabled, then it will not be able to fetch all rows.

Comment: I think you didn't get my question.

Comment: In this case pagination is not working, all the records are on 1 page which is I don't want

Comment: I have added explanation in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example from the DataTables website, where you are able to export your entire table as a JSON file.

Make sure you include the corresponding scripts and stylesheets.

Here is a link to the same exact code in a fiddle, which works: https://jsfiddle.net/BeerusDev/gf1pbvu8/

On SO it says trying to establish secure connection..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                text: 'JSON',
                action: function ( e, dt, button, config ) {
                    var data = dt.buttons.exportData();
 
                    $.fn.dataTable.fileSave(
                        new Blob( [ JSON.stringify( data ) ] ),
                        'Export.json'
                    );
                }
            }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.11.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.0.1/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2009/01/12</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2012/03/29</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Airi Satou</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>33</td>
                <td>2008/11/28</td>
                <td>$162,700</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2012/12/02</td>
                <td>$372,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2012/08/06</td>
                <td>$137,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>55</td>
                <td>2010/10/14</td>
                <td>$327,900</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>39</td>
                <td>2009/09/15</td>
                <td>$205,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sonya Frost</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2008/12/13</td>
                <td>$103,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jena Gaines</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2008/12/19</td>
                <td>$90,560</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
                <td>Support Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2013/03/03</td>
                <td>$342,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Charde Marshall</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>36</td>
                <td>2008/10/16</td>
                <td>$470,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
                <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2012/12/18</td>
                <td>$313,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>19</td>
                <td>2010/03/17</td>
                <td>$385,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Silva</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>2012/11/27</td>
                <td>$198,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Paul Byrd</td>
                <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2010/06/09</td>
                <td>$725,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gloria Little</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>59</td>
                <td>2009/04/10</td>
                <td>$237,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bradley Greer</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2012/10/13</td>
                <td>$132,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Dai Rios</td>
                <td>Personnel Lead</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>35</td>
                <td>2012/09/26</td>
                <td>$217,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
                <td>Development Lead</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2011/09/03</td>
                <td>$345,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Yuri Berry</td>
                <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>40</td>
                <td>2009/06/25</td>
                <td>$675,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Caesar Vance</td>
                <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2011/12/12</td>
                <td>$106,450</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Doris Wilder</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>23</td>
                <td>2010/09/20</td>
                <td>$85,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
                <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/10/09</td>
                <td>$1,200,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>42</td>
                <td>2010/12/22</td>
                <td>$92,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2010/11/14</td>
                <td>$357,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>28</td>
                <td>2011/06/07</td>
                <td>$206,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Fiona Green</td>
                <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>48</td>
                <td>2010/03/11</td>
                <td>$850,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shou Itou</td>
                <td>Regional Marketing</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>20</td>
                <td>2011/08/14</td>
                <td>$163,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michelle House</td>
                <td>Integration Specialist</td>
                <td>Sydney</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2011/06/02</td>
                <td>$95,400</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Suki Burks</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>53</td>
                <td>2009/10/22</td>
                <td>$114,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
                <td>Technical Author</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/05/07</td>
                <td>$145,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
                <td>Team Leader</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>2008/10/26</td>
                <td>$235,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Martena Mccray</td>
                <td>Post-Sales support</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/03/09</td>
                <td>$324,050</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Unity Butler</td>
                <td>Marketing Designer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/12/09</td>
                <td>$85,675</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/12/16</td>
                <td>$164,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
                <td>Secretary</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>41</td>
                <td>2010/02/12</td>
                <td>$109,850</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
                <td>Financial Controller</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>62</td>
                <td>2009/02/14</td>
                <td>$452,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
                <td>Office Manager</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2008/12/11</td>
                <td>$136,200</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
                <td>Director</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>65</td>
                <td>2008/09/26</td>
                <td>$645,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Olivia Liang</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2011/02/03</td>
                <td>$234,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Bruno Nash</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>38</td>
                <td>2011/05/03</td>
                <td>$163,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>37</td>
                <td>2009/08/19</td>
                <td>$139,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Thor Walton</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2013/08/11</td>
                <td>$98,540</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Finn Camacho</td>
                <td>Support Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2009/07/07</td>
                <td>$87,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
                <td>Data Coordinator</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>64</td>
                <td>2012/04/09</td>
                <td>$138,575</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2010/01/04</td>
                <td>$125,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
                <td>Software Engineer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>56</td>
                <td>2012/06/01</td>
                <td>$115,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
                <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>43</td>
                <td>2013/02/01</td>
                <td>$75,650</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cara Stevens</td>
                <td>Sales Assistant</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>46</td>
                <td>2011/12/06</td>
                <td>$145,600</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Hermione Butler</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>47</td>
                <td>2011/03/21</td>
                <td>$356,250</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Lael Greer</td>
                <td>Systems Administrator</td>
                <td>London</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>2009/02/27</td>
                <td>$103,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
                <td>Developer</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>30</td>
                <td>2010/07/14</td>
                <td>$86,500</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Shad Decker</td>
                <td>Regional Director</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>51</td>
                <td>2008/11/13</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Michael Bruce</td>
                <td>Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Singapore</td>
                <td>29</td>
                <td>2011/06/27</td>
                <td>$183,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Donna Snider</td>
                <td>Customer Support</td>
                <td>New York</td>
                <td>27</td>
                <td>2011/01/25</td>
                <td>$112,000</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out the solution for this. Usually, static table will give you the data with the following code which @Waseem (The one who's asking this question) had figured out and told me.
This is his code:

```
function convertTableToArrayObject() { 
      var transactions = []; 
      var table = $('#transactionsList').DataTable(); 
      var data = table.rows().data(); 
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
          transactions.push(data[i]); 
      } 
      return transactions;
}
```

And this code work as expected. But I had a slightly different requirement, what I had was I had an input box and a checkbox inside the  tag that the table provides. So I changed the code to give me the updated values from the input box and the check box.

This is the code for my HTML but written in jQuery as the data comes from ajax call:

```
str += '<td id="ra' + i + j + '" ><input data-ra="' + i + j + '" style="width: 100px;" type="text" class="txtvalue1" value="' + data[i][j] + '"/></td>'
```

Data here comes in a matrix format so I have 'i' and 'j' as two variables and I am running 2 loops.

Below is the code jQuery code for updating the value in the text box.

```
$(document).on('change', ".txtvalue1", function () {
    var table = $("#queueTables").DataTable();
    var e = $(this).val();
    var t = $(this).data('ra');
    table.cell("#ra" + t + "").data('<input data-ra="' + t + '" style="width: 100px;" type="text" class="txtvalue1" value="' + e + '">');
});
```

Below is the HTML for checkbox:

```
str += '<td id="op' + i + '" style="border-color: #FFD200; text-align:center;"><input data-row="' + i + '" class="selStatus" type="checkbox" checked value="true"></td>'
```

Below is the jQuery for the checkbox:

```
$(document).on('change', ".selStatus", function () {
    var table = $("#queueTables").DataTable();
    var temp2 = $(this).data('row');
    if ($(".selStatus[data-row='" + temp2 + "']").is(':checked')) {
        table.cell("#op" + temp2 + "").data('<input data-row="' + temp2 + '" class="selStatus" type="checkbox" checked value="true">');
    } else {
        table.cell("#op" + temp2 + "").data('<input data-row="' + temp2 + '" class="selStatus" type="checkbox" value="false">');
    }
});
```

Below is the jQuery code which I call when I have to send the data from the table to the backend.

```
    function convertTableToArrayObject(tblObj) {
    var transactions = [];
    var table = $(tblObj).DataTable();
    var $headers = $(tblObj).find("th");
    var data = table.data().toArray();
    data.forEach(function (row, i) {
        transactions[i] = {};
        row.forEach(function (cell, j) {
            var abc = $($.parseHTML(cell));
            if (!abc.val()) {
                transactions[i][$($headers[j]).html()] = cell;
            } else {
                transactions[i][$($headers[j]).html()] = abc.val();
            }
        });
    });
        return transactions;
}
```

This is will the required output that you want. Where there is a dict, of a key:value pair, and key is the header and value is the value for required cell.